# Is there an official Warlock class for Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, warlock

I've been playing Pathfinder for a while, but have also been playing D&D 3.X since they were published. In D&D there is the Warlock class, but in Pathfinder I have yet to find such a class other than in a third-party release (Adamant Entertainment). Is there an official Warlock class for Pathfinder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

None of the 3.5 classes or feats that were released in "splatbooks" (books besides the core three) are likely to ever appear in Pathfinder, owing to legal issues.  Basically, they're considered Wizards' Product Identity, not Open Game Content, and can't be copied by Paizo, the makers of Pathfinder.

However, Pathfinder is fully 3.5 compatible.  You can play the Warlock as written or modify it to be more like the updated Pathfinder classes and it *should* work, rules-wise.  You might have some occasional issues that require some GM adjudication, but for the most part the class should work just fine.  This is true for virtually every splat-class in 3.5.

As far as official Pathfinder suggestions go...

Thematically (fluff-wise), the Witch is pretty near a Warlock.  Power from a (usually dark) otherworldly Patron, certain special abilities that aren't limited in uses per day, lots of manipulation and control abilities.  But I don't think that's what you're going for.

Mechanically, the Kinecticist is nearly a Warlock.  Most of his abilities are unlimited use, he has a thematic and modifiable blast power as one of the cornerstones of his class, his utility powers will vastly differentiate one from another.  You might want to consider it.

Comment: I did find a very good version of the "Warlock" conversion to Pathfinder on Giants in the Playground Forum that's currently being play-tested and revised called the "Avowed". It's got all the flavor of the Warlock. I'm not sure if it's going to be put into any publication, but at this point, I felt it was worth noting...

I've played it myself, and feel it's the perfect "Warlock" for Pathfinder, but that's my personal opinion, and is thus not really relevant for RAW, but I still felt it should be brought to peoples attention if they want to investigate it further for themselves...